# Multiple Custom Handles (via unique class names) for jQuery Slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, uislider, jquery-ui-slider

This is has sort of been asked before but I haven't found a straight answer.

```
$(".milestone-timeline .slider-area").slider({
  range: 'min',
  value: 298,
  min: 0,
  max: 884,
  values: [ 10, 280, 620, 850 ]    
});
$(".milestone-timeline .slider-area").slider("option", "disabled", true);
```

Okay, here I've created 4 different markers or .ui-slider-handle's.  Now, when the slider is created it will make,

```
<div class="slider-area">
  <div class="ui-slider-range"></div>
  <a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle"></a>
  <a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle"></a>
  <a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle"></a>
  <a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle"></a>
</div>
```

I'd like to apply a different class name to each of these handles at the time the slider is created.

In the [jQuery UI Slider Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#overview) it says,

> "The slider widget will create handle elements with the class 'ui-slider-handle' on
> initialization. **You can specify custom handle elements by creating and appending the
> elements and adding the 'ui-slider-handle' class before init.** It will only create the
> number of handles needed to match the length of value/values. For example, if you specify
> 'values: [1, 5, 18]' and create one custom handle, the plugin will create the other two."

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to go about creating and appending a custom 'ui-slider-handle'.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.  **Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the slider handle to the elements you're trying to turn into sliders, like this:

```
<div class="milestone-timeline">         
    <div class="ui-slider-handle"></div>
</div>
```

That works because you're still adding that custom element before the slider init function is called.

Comment: This worked!  I just simply added my custom class 'red' to the <div class="ui-slider-handle red"></div> element that I hardcoded in.  It figured that was a handle and kept my custom class of 'red'.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

reading the documentation it looks like `values` is just a way of setting multiple slider handles. As is, it doesn't look like you can add classes.

you could possibly use nth-child selectors to add a class to each slider.

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: Thanks David!  I'm really trying to figure out how to "create custom handle elements, add custom classes, and append them before init."